# How to validate dynamic controls

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm having a table inside form tag in Angular. There's a text box and a dropdown. I want to validate them (Show error message if user doesn't input value or not selected drop down). When user clicks on a dropdown  dynamic input fields are generating based on API. I created form controls for the input text box and dropdown. I was unable to validate those dynamic input fields, how do I add them to validate? this is what I tried.

```js
this.customTableForm = new FormGroup({
  // created for static inputs
  'impName': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'tablelistDropdown': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
});

tableChanged(){
  // dynamic table values are coming from here
  this.importerService.listColumnData(this.selectedTable).subscribe(result => {
    this.columns = result['data'].columns;
  });
}

// Validations for input text and dropdown
get hasTableListDropDownError() {
  return (
    this.customTableForm.get('tablelistDropdown').touched &&
    this.customTableForm.get('tablelistDropdown').errors &&
    this.customTableForm.get('tablelistDropdown').errors.required
  )
}

get hasInputTextBoxErrorRequired() {
  const controller = this.customTableForm.get('impName');
  return controller.touched && controller.errors && controller.errors.required
}
```

[image]

Comment: Each rows have input and dropdown?

Comment: Dynamic forms has only name (label) and input text. Let's say if you click the item1 from dropdown it will generate 5 input boxes and labels. When click dropdown 2 it will show 3 input boxes and labels.

Comment: Since its dynamic inputs on select, you should update the validation. Inside the subscription this.customTableForm.get('impName').updateValueAndValidity()

Comment: Don't I need to create custom controls for that? I'm new

Comment: You should use formGroupArray... try to find what is formGroupArray. I will update soon

Comment: If you update an image of ur ui, that will be helpful

Comment: I updated an image with how dynamic fields are generating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197784/discussion-between-hiranya-and-varman).

Comment: Can you help @varman?

Comment: continue in the discussion chat

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully... this is what you expected. Please check this out in stackblitz. [Dynamically changing form group with validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-rows-dynamically-formgroup-formarray-mu33ku)